Matrix parenthesization problem expressed as Markov decision problem
I am trying to understand the relation between dynamic programming an Markov decision processes because I noticed many dynamic programming problems can be expressed in a MDP. In particular, I am trying to write classic dynamic programming problems as MDPs (deterministic actually, no probabilities here).
Rod cutting : Given a rod of length n, the states would be $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and if we are in state $i$, there is an action $a_j$ to go to state $j\in \{1,\ldots, i\}$ which means we cut a size $i-j$ of the rod, get a revard of $r(i, a_j)=price(i-j)$ and end up with a rod of size $j$. At the beginning of the problem, we are in state $n$ and we have to make optimal decisions to maximize the total profit, cutting the rod until we have nothing left.
matrix parenthesization: Given a chain of matrix to multiply $A_1\ldots A_n$ the state is the subchain we consider, i.e. state $(s,t)$ would be $A_s\ldots A_t$ and we can choose an action $a_k$ for $k\in \{s,t\}$ which means that we multiply first $A_s\ldots A_k$ and then $A_{k+1}\ldots A_t$. But how do you model this with a MDP? Indeed the action $a_k$ cannot go from state $(s,t)$ to two different state $(s, k)$ and $(k+1, t)$. I don't see how to represent this nicely in a MDP.
